# Thermal stability of solar cells

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, stability, solar-cells

Concerning the construction of solar cells which property is referred to when researchers speak about thermal stability of solar cells?

Comment: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/adma.201600281/full looks like they track PCE vs. exposure to heat

Answer (score 0):

Because a solar cell consists of thin layers of semiconductor materials in which the operation of the cell depends upon the integrity of the junctions that are formed between those layers, a cell's ability to generate electrical power will be compromised by anything that compromises those junctions. Chief of these is heat, which enables solid state diffusion to become active. Once the materials on opposite sides of the junction can freely interdiffuse, the junction is ruined and the cell stops working. This imposes a maximum operating temperature limit on the cell which must not be exceeded during its operational lifetime.

Cells whose construction is more resistant to heat damage by this mechanism are said to exhibit improved thermal stability compared to other cells. thermal stability is important because current efforts to minimize the cell area needed to produce a given quantity of electric power use concentrators that focus lots of sunlight onto a small cell area, which heats the cell and can destroy it.

Comment: Many thanks in advance for your answer. On the other hand, when researchers say that a compound like Cs_x MA_(1-x) exhibits enhanced thermal stability as compared to perovskites like MAPbI3 How do they obtain those results? Perharps do you know about papers where this topic is discussed, in particular comparing these two compounds?, thank you again

Comment: I do not know how they accomplish that in detail, but the experiment is straightforward: you take an operating photocell and attach it to a heated fixture. you raise its temperature in slow steps and note the point at which its output begins to fall. at that point you decrease the temperature, repeat the test, and see if its output remains low at the lower temperature. if it does, the cell has been permanently damaged.